# How to get values from a list of dictionaries, which themselves contain lists of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, subset

I encountered the problem of getting values from a list that contains dictionaries, where each of the dictionaries has a list with a dictionary. May sound easy to do but it took me some time and I think it can be useful for other people if I post it. An example of my data can be:

> ```
> player_info = [{[{'tag': 'tag 1'}]},
>                {[{'tag': 'tag 2'}]}]
> ```

The outer list is called 'player_info'. This contained 25 dictionaries, where each one contains a list that contains (among other things) a dictionary called 'opponent' which contains a list that contains a dictionary (yeah, pretty messy). From that innermost dictionary, I wanted the value associated with the 'tag' key.

I figured two ways:

1. Create a loop.

> ```
> for i in range(25):
>     print(player_info[i]['opponent'][0]['tag'])
> ```

2. Iterate through list:

> ```
> {each_dictionary['opponent'][0]['tag'] for each_dictionary in player_info}
> ```

I assume that the second way must be more efficient. Let me know what you think, and whether there is a smarter way to do it.

Comment: It would be helpful to include a small representative example of your current data structure and what your desired result is.

Comment: @jarmod I did it. I hope it is useful for somebody else!

Comment: I don't see `opponent` or an example of your desired result.

Comment: don't worry about optimization at this stage. you might change your data structure in a future, like creating classes. so for now both options should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: `dict`'s require a key-value association for every element in the dictionary. Your 2nd level data structure though does not include keys: (`{[{'tag': 'tag 1'}]}`) This is a `set`. Unlike `dict`'s, `set`'s do not have keys associated with their elements. So your data structure looks like `List[Set[List[Dict[str, str]]]]`.

Second: when I try to run

```py
# python 3.8.8
player_info = [{[{'tag': 'tag 1'}]},
               {[{'tag': 'tag 2'}]}]
```

I recieve the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. That's because you're code attempts to contain a list inside a set. Set membership in python demands the members to be hashable. However, you will not find a `__hash__()` function defined on `list` objects. Even if you resolve this by replacing the `list` with a `tuple`, you will find that `dict` objects are not hashable either. Potential solutions include using immutable objects like `frozendict` or `tuple`, but that is another post.

To answer your question, I have reformulated your problem as

```py
player_info = [[[{'tag': 'tag 1'}]],
               [[{'tag': 'tag 2'}]]]
```

and compared the performance difference with A) explicit loops:

```py
for i in range(len(player_info)):
  print(player_info[i][0][0]['tag'])
```

against B) list comprehension

```py
[
  print(single_player_info[0][0]['tag']) 
  for single_player_info in player_info
]
```

Running the above code blocks in jupyter with the `%%timeit` cell magic, I got:
A) `154 µs ± 14.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)` and
B) `120 µs ± 11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)`

Note: This experiment is highly skewed for at least two reasons:

1. I tested both trials using only the data you provided (N=2). It is very likely that we would observe different scaling behaviors than initial conditions suggest.
2. `print` consumes a lot of time and makes this problem heavily subject to the status of the kernel

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Perhaps I made a mistake when trying to provide the simplest possible example. I will review it.